# Get background image with Nokogiri from DOM?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm scraping a site and I can't get the images, because they are loaded with background-image CSS.

Is there a way to get these attributes with Nokogiri without having to use Phantom.js or Sentinel? The background-image actually uses inline-styles so I should be able to.

I have to get images from an array of URLS:

```
<div class="zoomLens" style="background-image: url(http://resources1.okadirect.com/assets/en/new/catalogue/1200x1200/EHD005MET-L_01.jpg?version=7); background-position: -14.7368421052632px -977.894736842105px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">&nbsp;</div>
```

I'm using Nokogiri via Mechanize, but don't know how to write this correctly:

```
image = agent.get(doc.parser.at('.zoomLens')["background-image"]).save("okaimages/f_deco-#{counter}.jpg")
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd use something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div class="zoomLens" style="background-image: url(http://resources1.okadirect.com/assets/en/new/catalogue/1200x1200/EHD005MET-L_01.jpg?version=7); background-position: -14.7368421052632px -977.894736842105px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">&nbsp;</div>')

doc.search('.zoomLens').map{ |n| n['style'][/url\((.+)\)/, 1] }
# => ["http://resources1.okadirect.com/assets/en/new/catalogue/1200x1200/EHD005MET-L_01.jpg?version=7"]
```

The trick is the appropriate pattern to grab the contents of the parenthesis. `n['style'][/url\((.+)\)/, 1]` is using [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) which can take a regular expression with grouping, and return a particular group from the captures. See https://www.regex101.com/r/mV6rY6/1 for a breakdown of what its doing.

At that point you'd be sitting on an array of image URLs. You can easily iterate over the list and use OpenURI or any number of other HTTP clients to retrieve the images.

Comment: The thing is I need this to work with dynamic routes that I have in an array (I have about 3000), so Isnt this code going to change for each?

Comment: Then you really need to write a question that reflects that right? We can only answer based on what you tell us and that wasn't part of your input or mentioned as a spec. Telling us a little, then changing and asking a different question, etc., isn't good. Put it all in at first.

Comment: Sorry about that, will specify it.

Comment: *IF* they are all specified using the `url(...)` form then it'll work as long as the tag uses the `zoomLens` class. If that isn't true, then you have to modify the code to fit.

Comment: Yes, the attributes are the same in every URL + the zoomLens class. Will try it.

Comment: @theTinMan, thank you for the answer. But how can I modify the URLs?

Comment: This is a really old question, and your question in a comment is not the SO way. You should ask a separate, new question about that specific problem. To get you started, you should investigate Ruby's URI class and the Addressable gem. Research, read the documentation, experiment, then ask when you've run into a brick wall that you couldn't overcome after days of hard work.